# return byte array in jni android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need get byte array from jni to Java.
Ex: I have a byte array byte[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_vn_getArray (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
  jbyte[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  return a;
```

}

I do not know how to return a byte array from jni.

Can someone help me? Please!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Java, an array is an object. So to hand a byte array from C or C++ over to java you will need to instantiate a jbyteArray, and return that. Instead of a C array. To solve that, see the following code:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_Test_returnArray
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject This)
{
        jbyte a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        jbyteArray ret = env->NewByteArray(6);
        env->SetByteArrayRegion (ret, 0, 6, a);
        return ret;
}
```

Based on this [link](https://community.oracle.com/message/6483346#6483346)

Comment: Do you get any exception? What is the return value you can see on the Java side?

Comment: @DungQuang Please check the code now, I had some more time to look at it and fixed a rather embarrassing compiler error. The edited code works for me, and gives me back a byte array on the Java side with a count of six.

Comment: tks, I resolved this problem by the code bellowing:
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_example_json_bo_getArrray
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject o) {
  jbyte a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
 jbyteArray ret = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, 6);
 (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion (env, ret, 0, 6, a);
 return ret;
}
tks for help!

Answer (score 4):

I do like that and it's working

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_vn_getArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    jbyte byteUrl[] = {1,2,3,3,4};
    int sizeByteUrl = 5;

    jbyteArray data = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, sizeByteUrl);
    if (data == NULL) {
        return NULL; //  out of memory error thrown
    }

    // creat bytes from byteUrl
    jbyte *bytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, data, 0);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeByteUrl; i++) {
        bytes[i] = byteUrl[i];
    }

    // move from the temp structure to the java structure
    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, data, 0, sizeByteUrl, bytes);

    return data;
}
```

Comment: You would need to call ReleaseByteArrayElements to release bytes when you are done.